# How to use .ToDictionary() extension method on DataRow

Tags: c#, linq

I need a `Dictionary<string,object>` which is produced from a DataRow.  I currently have something for this working, but I am doing way too much and not utilizing the .ToDictionary() extension method.

Can someone please enlighten me on how to accomplish this successfully?

Here is my failed attempt:

```
var dataDictionary = dataTable.Select(acn + "=" + accountNumber).ToDictionary(key => key.Table.Columns);
```

This returns a `KeyValuePair<DataColumnCollection, DataRow>`, but again, I need a `Dictionary<string,object>`

Thanks again in advance!

Comment: You forgot to mention what you want as key and value ? Your question doesn't really make sense without that. I'll post an answer using general terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - i think i can make that work.  my key needs to be the column name and my value needs to be the value for that column in the datarow.

Comment: Hmm - are you selecting multiple rows or should your `Select` only match a single one ?

Comment: I am matching one row. Apologies - what I have is ugly - my datatable for this instance only has one row and that is what I am creating the dictionary from.  What I need is something like `Dictionary<string, string>{{"Acn", "7070707"}, {"Name", "John Smith"}}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specifiy the key you want, which might be the `acn` column in the table:

```
.ToDictionary(row => (string)row["acn"]);
```

ToDictionary takes a second delegate if you want to run a transformation on the values in the returned dictionary.

## Edit

I'll leave the original answer since it explains the general case. You want to take a single row; then use it's columns as keys and the column values as the, well, values. This is how you do that.

```
 DataRow row = dataTable.Select(acn + "=" + accountNumber).Single(); // You might want SingleOrDefault
 var dataDictionary = row.Table.Columns.ToDictionary(col => col.Name, col => row[col.Name]);
```

*Disclaimer, the above was written without a compiler at hand, might need a bit tweaking.*

Comment: The above code is okay but was "written without a compiler". Be sure to use @jjoelson's answer instead.

Answer (score 27):

I know this is old, but for those that come along later the correct LINQ expression is a slight modification of driis's code:

```
var dictionary = row.Table.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => row.Field<string>(col.ColumnName));
```

Answer (score 2):

@jjoelson's answer produces a `Dictionary<string, string>`. If you want a `Dictionary<string, object>`, you could, of course, do:

```
var dictionary = row.Table.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => row.Field<object>(col.ColumnName));
```

But a slightly less convoluted version is:

```
var dictionary row.Table.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => row[col]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I like LINQ

```
dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(e=>e.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => e[col.ColumnName]) ).ToList()
```